# Segmentation fault accessing characters of a std::string

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stdstring

I'm one of those new guys that learned Java first then came to C++ and a lot of things are weird. I'm trying to access characters of a std::string object in order to recognize spaces (yes, I want to go the hard way first, no regex for now), however I'm getting a segmentation fault error that I can't understand. The error is being thrown upon call of the "getTokens()" function, which calls the toTokenize.at() method which is the one throwing segmentation fault. If someone can point me in the right way, I would be really grateful! Find my code below. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::string> getTokens(const std::string& toTokenize) {

    std::vector<std::string> result;

    for (int i=1; i<toTokenize.length(); i++) {
        std::cout << toTokenize.at(i);
    }

}


int main() {

    std::string s ("");

    do {

        std::cout << "\nPlease input a command: ";
        getline(std::cin, s);

        getTokens(s);

    }
    while (s != "exit");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this the complete program ? `getTokens` is not returning anything. Also loop iteration starts from 0.

Comment: Yes, this is. I wanted to do complete the program but got stuck in this error. No problem with that. The problem is, as soon as getTokens() is called, it throws segmentation fault.

Comment: @zorman2000 it does not crash "as soon as getTokens() is called", it crashes when you exit the function without a proper return object; you can prove that by stepping through in a debugger. You do not see the output prior to that because output is buffered, and you crash before the buffer is flushed.

Comment: You're right my friend, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getTokens` isn't returning anything

Fixes as follows :-

```
std::vector<std::string> getTokens(const std::string& toTokenize) {
     //^^make it as void, if nothing is to be returned
    std::vector<std::string> result;

     //start from zero
    for (size_t i=0; i<toTokenize.length(); i++) {
        std::cout << toTokenize.at(i);
    }

return result;
        //^^or return value, however, result isn't used here
}
```

Comment: That does it, it's just that the function is not returning anything... oh my, why does C++ has to complain about that?

Comment: @zorman2000 I think a better question would be "why does the compiler not complain about that?" -- I'm not sure why this isn't caught at compile time rather than run time (though if you compile with g++ and use the -Wall option, it does emit a warning).

Comment: @mah I agree. A decent compiler should emit a warning. It is easy to get GCC to do so: `warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]`.

Comment: Yes, well, does it have anything to do that I'm using cmake for building this?

Comment: @zorman2000 I don't know cmake, but I'm sure it allows you to add compile flags... if you're using gcc/g++, I would recommend adding `-Wall -Wextra` (all doesn't actually mean all!) to see a better range of warnings. You might also choose to add `-Werror`, which treats all warnings as errors.